# Are shift mappings of Android NDK keycodes standardized?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am wondering whether there is an official reference as to how certain keycodes are passed through the Android NDK. Take the question mark (`?`) for example. AFAICS, there is no `AKEYCODE_XXX` definition in `keycodes.h` for the question mark. I did some tests and it looks like the question mark keycode is actually sent as `AKEYCODE_SLASH` with shift on, i.e. `AKeyEvent_getMetaState()` has the `AMETA_SHIFT_ON` flag set.

The same can be observed for other keycodes, here are few examples:

- `{` is sent as `AKEYCODE_LEFT_BRACKET` with shift on
- `}` is sent as `AKEYCODE_RIGHT_BRACKET` with shift on
- `:` is sent as `AKEYCODE_SEMICOLON` with shift on
- `>` is sent as `AKEYCODE_PERIOD` with shift on
- `<` is sent as `AKEYCODE_COMMA` with shift on
- etc.

It pretty much seems to conform to the mappings on a standard US keyboard. However, there are some exceptions:

- on a US keyboard, the `*` is normally generated by pressing `8` plus shift; Android, however, has its own `AKEYCODE_STAR` for the `*` character
- also, on a US keyboard the `+` is normally generated by pressing `=` plus shift; Android, however, has its own `AKEYCODE_PLUS` definition here

To cut a long story short, I was wondering whether there is some official explanation of this behaviour. Is this documented and standardized behaviour? Is there a table or something in the official Android developer docs that shows how certain keycodes should be treated if shift is on? I.e. is there a table in the Android docs that says that `AKEYCODE_SEMICOLON` has to be treated as `:` if shift is on? Or is this all undocumented behaviour?

Furthermore, I'm interested if this behaviour is consistent across all Android versions and locales, e.g. will the shift mapping described above also hold true on Chinese Android phones?

Finally, what about combining shift with keys which are already shift keys on a US keyboard? e.g. `AKEYCODE_STAR` and `AKEYCODE_PLUS`. Can it also happen that those are sent with shift on and do they have to be mapped to some other keys than as well?

I hope somebody can shed some light on this. Thanks!